# How to partially update JSON file

Tags: c#, json

I have a json file that has multiple arrays that looks something like this:

```
{
 "Array1":{
    "Test1": "Answer1",
    "Test2": "Answer2",
    "Test3": "Answer3"
  },
 "Array2":{
    "Test4": "Answer4",
    "Test5": "Answer5",
    "Test6": "Answer6"
  },
 "Array3":{
    "Test7": "Answer7",
    "Test8": "Answer8",
    "Test9": "Answer9"
  }
}
```

I am already updating my objects that hold this information, but my question is **Is it possible to partially update the FILE itself?** For example if I wanted to update just Array2 rather than rewrite the whole file. I searched the interwebs but couldn't find an answer...everything I found talked about updating the objects. I want to partially update the file itself. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know if you can write to a custom part, but the length is different, it seems impossible.

Comment: Files really don't work that way, especially if you are replacing data that is longer or shorter than the original data. Binary files may have space reserved for "records", but text files are just collections of characters saved on disk. The easiest way to do it is to load the entire file, make the changes, then write it back to the file. You can overwrite portions of a file, but you have to take care to preserve data.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thats what I was afraid of lol. Theres another way around what I'm working on, this just would have been definitely a more direct approach.