# Changing values in json file with go

Tags: json, go

I've got a small json file

```
{
    "first": "",
    "second": ""
}
```

and I want to ocasionally modify its values.
I managed to open the file using `Unmarshal` but I don't know how to change its values.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

type Data struct {
    First string `json:"first"`
    Second string `json:"second"`
}

func main() {

    //read json file with io/ioutil
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("temp.json")

    var data Data

    json.Unmarshal(file, &data)
}
```

I saw that you can `Marshal` and it should change the json file by the `Data` struct but I don't want to rewrite the file everytime just to modify a single value. Is there a way to change by variable or I do have to use the `Marshal` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the entire file into memory, make changes and write back to the file. In order to manipulate JSON structured objects more easily, add your encode & decode steps:

```
1. JSON file    (A) ----- read -----------> file content (B, text)
2. file content (B) ----- json decode ----> json object  (C, structured)
3. json object  (C) ----- change value ---> json object  (D)
4. json object  (D) ----- json encode ----> new content  (E)
5. new content  (E) ----- write ----------> JSON file    (F)
```

If you are asking about "if it possible to partially update the file itself", it can be a duplicate of [How to partially update JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52322533/1592264).

The APIs you can use in Go that the package [encoding/json](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json) provided are:

- [Encoder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Encoder)
- [Decoder](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder)
- [Marshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal)
- [Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal)